# Jquery load not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I have this code:

`function content(){
    $("#23").load("http://www.example.com/index.html", alert('responded'));
    }`

Which is triggered when the body loads. It does complete the `alert` but it does not do anything to `<div id="23"></div>` located on the page.

Any ideas why?

I am brand spanking new to jquery so sorry if this is a very simple mistake.

Update: After using the code suggested and then changing some stuff in Xcode I am able to have cross domain working well. Thanks Heaps.

Comment: It does not seem to change it, I can try to load it from a same origin location and it still responds but will not change the contents of the div, I was able to get it to alert the received HTML but it would not change the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing the `callback` in a wrong way, replace your `function` with this:

```
function content() { 
    $('#23').load('http://www.example.com/index.html', function() {
        alert('responded');
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Is this effected by cross origin?

Comment: Yes, you can't load something that is not in your domain (depending of the website rules, for example, I think Yahoo can load this way but lots of others not)

Answer (score 1):

The callback needs to be a function jQuery can execute when the call completes. Using alert with the `()` will immediately execute the function. You can wrap the alert call in an `anonymous function` that jQuery can use when the Ajax call is complete.

```
function content() { 
    $("#23").load("http://www.example.com/index.html", function() {
        alert('responded');
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Is this effected by cross origin?

Comment: Yes, the URL needs to be on your same domain. jQuery can handle cross domain requests with JSONP. You will have to drop to a lower lever API of $.ajax. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: So people use this JSONP when they are communicating between a native app and a server to get PHP requests?